# How to move from one ng-route to another of different module

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc and angularjs for a project.
I have created two module register and item.Both module have there ng-views and routing engine. Things are working till here, but now i want to open item module routing page from register module button click.

Register Module..

```
var registerModule = angular.module('registerModule', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'App/Register/view/RegisterView.html', controller: 'RegisterController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/setup', { templateUrl: 'App/Register/view/SetupCompany.html', controller: 'setupController' });

});
```

Item Module....

```
var itemModule = angular.module('itemModule', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'App/Item/Views/ItemList.html', controller: 'itemlistController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/Details', { templateUrl: 'App/Item/Views/ItemDetails.html', controller: 'itemDetailController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/Add', { templateUrl: 'App/Item/Views/AddItem.html', controller: 'addItemController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/Import', { templateUrl: 'App/Item/Views/ImportItemExcel.html', controller: 'ImportController' });

});
```

Now on ng-click i want to have something like:

$location.path('/Item');

I tried to use service also, i was hitting the mvc controller action but the view was not returned :

> ```
> registerService.gotoDashboard();
> ```

registerService:

```
registerModule.service("registerService", function ($http) {
 this.gotoDashboard = function () {
        return $http.get("Item/Index");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$location.path should do it.

$http is to make http request to servers, it won't affect your current route.

However i see that you're trying to get to a route with /Item or Item/Index, but i don't see any definition of those URLS in your routeProvider configuration. Did you skip some route definition or did you forget these routes in your own code ?

Comment: Actually when i am manually entering localhost:4567/Item, the ItemList.html template strike..  and by giving $location.path("Item/Details");    i am getting localhost:4567/register#/item/details  but i want localhost:4567/#item/details

Comment: And Item/Index is my mvc route where Item is controller and Index is Action ...  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

Comment: Is your application one page ? If not i suggest you to use the base tag in order to set the path to '/' otherwise angular will always refer to the current path as the base. So you won't be able to navigate between multiple page.